# discord.py receive a link to a message after sending it

Tags: discord.py

I'm sorry for my poor English.

I created a bot that outputs a Google image that corresponds to a string when I enter a string through a discord command.

Here is the code:

```
    file = discord.File(f"C:/Python Data/downloads/{image}/a.gif", filename="a.gif")

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{image}", color=ctx.author.color)
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://a.gif")
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    global msg
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(file=file,embed=embed)
    a = [image] + [msg's message link]
    shutil.rmtree(fr"C:/Python Data/downloads/{image}")
```

I want to make is I'd like to get a link to the message after the bot sends the message.
I'd like to implement this part of "msg's message link".

I want to know if this is possible.
What should I do if possible?

If my question is not clear, please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a link to "jump" to the message you can get it with `msg.jump_url` ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.jump_url))

Your code doesnt quite show the way you want to use the link (nor do you explain its use), so this is the most i can help you

Comment: You're right.
Thank you so much.
Have a good day.